# python/numpy: Using own data structure with np.allclose() ? Where to look for the requirements / what are they?

Tags: python, numpy, magic-methods, type-coercion

I'm implementing a Matrix Product State class, which is some kind of special tensor decomposition scheme in python/numpy for fast algorithm prototyping.

I don't think that there already is such a thing out there, and I want to do it myself to get a proper understanding of the scheme.

What I want to have is that, if I store a given tensor T in this format as T_mps, I can access the reconstructed elements by T_mps[ [i0, i1, ..., iL] ]. This is achieved by the **getitem**(self, key) method and works fine.

Now I want to use numpy.allclose(T, mps_T) to see if my decomposition is correct.

But when I do this I get a type error for my own type:

> TypeError: function not supported for these types, and can't coerce safely to supported types

I looked at the documentation of allclose and there it is said, that the function works for "array like" objects. Now, what is this "array like" concept and where can I find its specification ?

Maybe I'm better off, implementing my own allclose method ? But that would somewhat be reinventing the wheel, wouldn't it ?

Appreciate any help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "arraylike" is used in the numpy documentation to mean "anything that can be passed to numpy.asarray() such that it returns an appropriate numpy.ndarray." Most sequences with proper `__len__()` and `__getitem__()` methods work okay. Note that the `__getitem__(i)` must be able to accept a single integer index in `range(len(self))`, not just a list of indices as you seem to indicate. The result from this `__getitem__(i)` must either be an atomic value that numpy knows about, like a float or an int, or be another sequence as above. Without more details about your Matrix Product State implementation, that's about all I can help.

Comment: The `__len__(i)` getitem(i) approach doesn't really fit my datastructure, because each coefficient of the tensor is internally stored as a product of matrices (hence the name). 
I found another approach here:
[link](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2001-September/013212.html) There the array() function is used, but reconstructing the whole tensor as a numpy array defeats the whole purpose of the scheme.
So I think I'll just shift the work to the testcases to sample some entries using the getitem([.....]) function. It is for debugging purposes only, anyway.